# Two vectors sequence one to another

Tags: r, vector, sequence

I have two vectors `c(1,2)` and `c(9,10)`
and I want have outputs as follows:

`c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` and `(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

it seems simple but I can't figure it out...

thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to create a `list` of `vector`s.  Here, the `:` will get the sequence of values from each corresponding elements of 'v1' and 'v2'

```
Map(`:`, v1, v2)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 1:2
v2 <- 9:10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!  it work and really helpfull